# postgresql RETURNING in zf2 table gateway

Tags: postgresql, zend-framework2

How would one add a RETURNING clause in insert via table gateway ?

```
INSERT INTO users (name, age) VALUES ('Liszt', 10) RETURNING id;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$dataArray = array('name'=> 'Liszt','age' => 10);
$this->tableGateway->insert($dataArray);
$userId = $this->tableGateway->lastInsertValue;
```

Another method is :

```
$userId = $this->tableGateway->getLastInsertValue();
```

Comment: Using `$this->tableGateway->lastInsertValue;` or `$this->tableGateway->getLastInsertValue();` i get NULL value

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get last insert id in postgresql when inserting into tablegateway you have to use SequenceFeature.

```
$myTable = new TableGateway('table_name', $dbAdapter, new Feature\SequenceFeature('primary_key', 'sequence_name'));
$id = $myTable->insert(array(/*your data*/));
```

Comment: instead of :
`$id = $myTable->insert(array(/*your data*/));`
i had to put:
`$myTable->insert(array(/*your data*/));
$id = $myTable->lastInsertValue`

But from the code at [github-SequenceFeature](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Db/TableGateway/Feature/SequenceFeature.php)

it is clear that this solution is still making two trips to the database, and thats what im trying to avoid here

it seems to me that it isnt possible to get this done with a single trip to db using zf2

Comment: Oh, sorry. I was in ZF1 in my mind. In ZF2 is correct way: insert, get last value.

You can extend TableGateway:

```
<?php

MyTableGateway extends TableGateway
{
    public function insert($data)
    {
        parent::insert($data);
        return $this->getLastInsertValue();
    }
}
```